# Google cloud Datastore GQL - Get current datetime

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

Is it possible to make a google datastore GQL query with a comparison on the current DateTime?

Example:

```
select * from MY_KIND where created_at < DATETIME.NOW
```

I've seen anything about that on any post or google documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference

I need to make an operation on data older than 30 days.

Comment: what query did you use to get data older than 30 days?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative approach by trying to fetch entries after a particular date.

```
SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE date > DATETIME(yyyy,mm,dd)
```

The right-hand side of a comparison can be one of the following:

- A datetime, date, or time literal, with either numeric values or a string representation, in the following forms:

  > `DATETIME(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
  >   DATETIME('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
  >   DATE(year, month, day)
  >   DATE('YYYY-MM-DD')
  >   TIME(hour, minute, second)
  >   TIME('HH:MM:SS')`

*Hope this answers your question!!*